# Pull only the most recent record value into index Blade @foreach in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my index blade of equipment, I have the following lines:

```
            @foreach ($equipment as $equipment)

                 <tr>
                     <td><a href="/origins/{{$equipment['id']}}">{{$equipment['unit_id']}}</a></td>
                      <td>{{$equipment->unit_type}}</td>
                      <td>{{\Crypt::decryptString($equipment->VIN)}}</td>
                     <td>{{\Crypt::decryptString($equipment->licensePlate)}}</td>
                     <td>{{\Crypt::decryptString($equipment->titleNumber)}}</td>
                     <td>{{$equipment->registrations}}</td>
                </tr>

            @endforeach
```

As you can see, the last column pulls in "registrations". As they sit now, they arrive as an array such as below:

```
[{"id":45,"equipmentID":368,"amountDue":"0.00","emissions":0,"createdBy":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"expirationDate":"2015-05-31"},{"id":63,"equipmentID":368,"amountDue":"0.00","emissions":0,"createdBy":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"expirationDate":"2014-03-31"},{"id":274,"equipmentID":368,"amountDue":"1594.57","emissions":0,"createdBy":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"expirationDate":"2012-11-30"}]
```

How would I go about sorting it so the record with the most recent "expirationDate" comes first and the date itself is the thing printed to the index (in the above case, I'd be looking for the date 2015-05-31)?

Would this be an attribute through the model?

My current relationship between the two models (the equipment and the registrations) is defined as such:

```
public function registrations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EquipmentLicense::class,'equipmentID','id');
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the equipements? `$registration::with('registrations')` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the date itself is the thing printed to the index"?

Comment: @SergioReis - through the controller I just use this function:         public function index()
            {
                $equipment = Equipment::all();
                return view('equipment.index', compact('equipment'));
            }

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - I mean, I just want the "expirationDate" field of the "lastest" (using the expirationDate) record to appear on the index.

Comment: So `<td>2015-05-31</td>`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir - correct

Comment: You can define orderBy method on relation and then display first result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need the latest registration, a `HasOne` relationship is sufficient:

```
public function registration()
{
    return $this->hasOne(EquipmentLicense::class,'equipmentID','id')
        ->orderByDesc('expirationDate');
}
```

Then access it in your view:

```
<td>{{$equipment->registration->expirationDate}}</td>
```

To reduce the number of database queries you should use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$equipment = Equipment::with('registration')->get();
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, mainly because I've never needed it before, but if say at some point I needed all of the previous registrations, could I add another relationship to the model similar to the one above,  but have a different name such as registrationAll() ? As in, can one model have multiple relationships to another? And I'll look into the eager loading, I feel like this will be extremely useful for other sections.

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks again for everything!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like

```
<td>{{$equipment->registrations->sortByDesc('expirationDate')->first()}}</td>
```

But it looks ugly to do thiis in your view, also, you're doing 1 query per line doing this, which may cause the application to be slower.

Really recomend looking at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Something with the looks of

```
$equipements = Equipment::with("registrations");

foreach($equipements as $equipement){
   $equipement->lastRegistration = $equipement->registrations->sortByDesc('expirationDate')->first();
}
```

and in your view,

```
<td>{{$equipment->lastRegistration ? $equipment->lastRegistration->expirationDate : ''}}</td>
```

Comment: `$equipement->lastRegistration = $equipement->registrations->sortByDesc('expirationDate')->first();` still isn't best practice here imo, but it does get the job done